# Question about time, speed, distance and fuel consumed

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> A truck travelling at $70 \frac{km}{h}$ uses 30% more diesel to travel a certain distance than it does when it travels at a speed of $50 \frac{km}{h}$. If the truck can travel $19.5 \frac{km}{L}$ of diesel at $50 \frac{km}{h}$, how far can the truck travel on $10 L$ of diesel at a speed of $70 \frac{km}{h}$?

What I understood
Let the amount of diesel used be $\frac{x}{L}$
In $70 \frac{km}{h}$ amount of diesel used be $1.3\frac{x}{L}$
In $50 \frac{km}{h}$ amount of diesel used be $\frac{x}{100}$
Now what to do next?

Answer (score 0):

Let x be the distance travelled at 70 km/hr on 1L of fuel.  Then x km/L is equal to 19.5km/1.3L (30% greater expenditure). Now, you will need to divide the numerator and denominator of the latter ratio by 1.3. Once you have your efficiency rate for traveling at 70 km/hr, you can apply that the final question.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The truck travels $50\frac{km}{hr}$ at a diesel usage rate of $19.5\frac{km}{L}$. Since the truck uses $30%$ more diesel while traveling at a speed of $70\frac{km}{hr}$, $\implies$ that the truck will travel $13.65\frac{km}{L}$ at a speed of $70\frac{km}{hr}$. Therefore, on a diesel of $10$L, it will travel a distance of $136.5$km.